# Lua mySQL update statements and where clauses

Tags: mysql, database, lua

So I'm trying to run an update with LuaSQL and mySQL, and seem to be stuck in one place. Whenever I try to update, the `WHERE` clause always fails on me, stating that the column doesn't exist. However, the column is correct, and the output gives a different column name. This is the update clause and what comes of it after running it

```
status,errorString = assert(conn:execute[[UPDATE Users SET count=count+1 WHERE userID = user#id50589297]]))

lua: test3.lua:16: LuaSQL: error executing query. MySQL: Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    test3.lua:16: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string `user#id50589297`, it's trying to parse it as a column identifier.

```
status, err = assert(
  conn:execute[[UPDATE Users SET count=count+1 WHERE userID='user#id50589297']]))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! So I figure I have to include quotes inside a variable if I were to use one?

Comment: In Lua, the `%q` format specifier will add quotes. But for security though, most SQL libraries provide escape functionality to avoid SQL injections that you should use. maybe `conn:escape`? I haven't done this with any Lua libraries.